# Feeding a SharePoint Document Library Documents Stored on a Network Share

Tags: sharepoint, esb

The question sounds pretty trivial, but an additional complexity is introduced by the fact that the documents are generated non-deterministically on the file share.  In addition, there is a requirement to make the box hosting the physical folder being shared; send a message to the SharePoint server that the document is done being generated, after which point the download occurs, followed by moving it to the document library (this post-message process I can handle)

There are multiple situations involving scenarios that require messaging such as these.  Would my client be a good candidate for an Enterprise Service Bus (or is that overkill?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use the document library's network share as the original write location of the documents?  Aren't documents written to a document library's network share added to that document library?

Comment: I would go with this approach 100%, however when I "Open In Windows Explorer" a document lib, it opens, but I only see a url, rather than unc i can map a network folder to.  If I were able to do this, i'd just be dropping off files into the mapped folder.  Going to mark this as answered.

Comment: A SharePoint URL can be addressed as a UNC path. e.g. http:/ /servername/doclibraryname/ when you click "Open in Windows Explorer" try using \\servername\doclibraryname\

Answer (score 1):

Can't you have the generating process email the document to the Document Library?  This is what we have done with most of our legacy, UNIX based report creation routines - email enable the document library and just mail the documents out.

Comment: Yes, that was definately a (good) solution put on the table.  Unfortunately the client doesn't care too much for the idea of email enabled libraries.